# Drawing specific curves in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, graphs

I have the following table to draw as a graph in LaTeX.

[image]

Notice that we don't have coordinates to be drawn. For each method, there is one accuracy value. For example the **Method 1** has an accuracy equal to **1.454**, the same for the other methods.

The question is how can I represent this table as a graph or curve showing the accuracy of each method ? For example the x-axis shows all the method possibilities (Method 1, Method 2, Method 3) while the accuracy values in the y-axis, etc. Kindly give me all the possibilities.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `pgfplots`, using `symbolic x coords`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  symbolic x coords={Method 1,Method 2, Method 3},
  xtick={Method 1,Method 2, Method 3},
  ytick={1.454,2.14,4.23},
  xticklabel style={rotate=-90},
  only marks, % removes lines between points
  ylabel={Accuracy}]

\addplot coordinates {(Method 1,1.454) (Method 2,2.14) (Method 3,4.23)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Or as a barplot:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ybar,
  symbolic x coords={Method 1,Method 2, Method 3},
  xtick={Method 1,Method 2, Method 3},
  nodes near coords,
%  ytick={1.454,2.14,4.23},
  xticklabel style={rotate=-90},
  ylabel={Accuracy}]

\addplot coordinates {(Method 1,1.454) (Method 2,2.14) (Method 3,4.23)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) can I write the values (1.454, 2.14,4.23) on the graph ?

Comment: @Christina See my updated answer. I added `only marks` because of overlap between the second label and the line. There are probably better ways of dealing with that though.

Comment: Ah no I mean to write the corresponding values on the drawing curve. Can you do this ?

Comment: @Christina I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean the yticks should be 1.454, 2.14, 4.23 instead of 2,3,4?

Comment: In fact each point has its own accuracy value. Can we draw the curve and show the accuracy value for each point on the y-axix at the same time in order to make the read of the curve more easy

Comment: @Christina Did I get it right now?

Comment: Method 1, Method 2 and Method 3 implies that there is nothing in between, so please: DO NOT CONNECT THE POINTS WITH STRAIGHT LINES.

Comment: @MaxNoe You have a point, so I've modified my code a bit, and updated the screenshot. (No need to shout though.)

Comment: A bar plot would also be nice since this is a symbolic plot. Nodes near coords would do the trick for the values.

Comment: @percusse I did suggest `nodes near coords` in an earlier revision, albeit without bars, but the OP didn't want that.  Anyways, I added a barplot example as well.

Answer (score 3):

Another presentation, as a bar chart, with the `pst-bar` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt, pdf, x11names]{article}%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pst-bar}
\newpsbarstyle{mine}{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=Thistle3!30!,linecolor=Thistle4}

\begin{document}

\sffamily
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(6,5)%
\psset{xunit=3, mathLabel=false}%
\psgrid[gridlabels=0, gridcolor=Thistle3, subgriddiv=0,griddots=30](0,0)(3,5)%
\psaxes[axesstyle=frame, Ox=0, Dx=1, labels=y, ylabelFontSize=\footnotesize, ticks=y, yticksize=-1.5pt 1.5pt, ytickcolor=Thistle3](0,0)(3,5)%
\psset{barcolsep =0.65, labelwidth = 2cm}%
\readpsbardata{\data}{methods.csv}%
\psbarchart[barstyle={mine}]{\data}
\footnotesize
\uput[u](0.5,1.454){1.454}
\uput[u](1.5, 2.14){2.14}
\uput[u](2.5, 4.23){4.23}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

It can be compiled with `pdfLaTeX` (`pdf` option for \documentclass) with the switch `--shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX)  or `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX).

[image]

Methods.csv file:

```
Method 1, Method 2, Method 3
1.454, 2.14, 4.23
```